# Bukkit - Getting a response from a PHP file

Tags: java, php, fopen, bukkit

I would like to make a Bukkit plugin using Java. In this plugin I would like to get a response from PHP file, `key.php?nick=gameplayer&code=key`.

If `$_GET['code']` is Ok, then server response should be 1, `else` it is 0.

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You might find help here, [How to write a Java Desktop App that interacts with my website's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984185/how-to-write-a-java-desktop-app-that-can-interact-with-my-websites-api), though it isn't Bukkit specific. Still Java, should still be help. ;)
If not, I would look into converting the code from your PHP to Java, there isn't much difference in what the two can do, especially with people being able to make their own APIs you could install to your plugin and use.